# Problem with the asymptotic behavior of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to evaluate:
$$
\sum_{n\leq x} \left[ \frac{ \sum_{d\mid n}\omega\left(d\right)  }{n} \right]
$$
where $\omega$ is a (generic) periodic function.

The standard approach involves the following steps:
$$
\sum_{qd\leq x}\left[\frac{\omega\left(d\right)}{qd} \right]=\sum_{d\leq x}\left[\frac{\omega\left(d\right)}{d} \sum_{q\leq x/d}\left[\frac{1}{q} \right]\right]
$$

Now, the inner sum behaves asymptotically as: 
$$
 \sum_{q\leq x/d}\left[\frac{1}{q} \right]=\log\left(\frac{x}{d}\right)+C+O\left(\frac{d}{x}\right)=\log\left(x\right)-\log\left(d\right)+C+O\left(\frac{d}{x}\right)
$$

We call 
$$
f\left(x\right)=\frac{\omega\left(x\right)}{x}
$$

and the sum becomes

$$
\sum_{qd\leq x}\left[\frac{\omega\left(d\right)}{qd} \right]=\sum_{d\leq x}\left[f\left(d\right)\left( \log\left(x\right)-\log\left(d\right)+C+O\left(\frac{d}{x}\right) \right)\right]
$$

Now, according to the book, this one should result into 
$$\log\left(x\right)\sum_{n\leq x}f\left(x\right)+O\left(1\right)$$
but I don't see how. Maybe I have made some mistake somewhere?

Comment: Do you mind clarifying this last statement: should it be $(\log x)\sum_{n \leq x} f(n)$? Also, I don't see where you've used the periodicity of $\omega$ yet.

Comment: yes, it is $f(n)$... 

As for the periodicity of $\omega$, how should it be leveraged?